# Finding a question similar to this one

Tags: discussion, questions, search

I recall seeing a question on VAEs last week, similar to this one but more verbose:

[Variational Autoencoder VS Normal Autoencoder](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324340/variational-autoencoder-vs-normal-autoencoder)

I remember the term "understand the basic math behind [them/VAE]" so I think it was a question from the same author. I can't find the question anymore and as I'm not a mod, I can't see if it has been deleted. Is there someone who can, and who would be willing to do it? :-) I don't think the question was closed, as I tried using `isclosed:yes` in my searches without success.

Comment: I don't see a deleted question like that from that user. A deleted question similar to that may exist from a different user, but I haven't found one.

Comment: @gung ok thanks, I must have remembered the user name incorrectly.